# Tensorflow's Inception - Number of Classes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm wondering about the number of classes in Tensorflow's [Inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) implementation.

In their [training script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py), they load the training set consisting of images and labels. Next, to calculate the loss, they define the [number of classes](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L220) as:

```
# Number of classes in the Dataset label set plus 1.
# Label 0 is reserved for an (unused) background class.
num_classes = dataset.num_classes() + 1
```

You can see that they use an "unused background class". You can also see this approach when they create their training set: [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py#L57)

So, why would you need such an unused background class? (Especially because you get one additional but useless prediction from the output layer)

Answer (score 2):

> It's a convention we use for all our image datasets, and it didn't seem worth the trouble to break it for this particular model.
>   As an aside, I wish all academic classification datasets had a **'none of the above' class** in their test evaluation. A classifier which doesn't know when it doesn't know is not that useful in practice. (vanhoucke)

https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/9G-c2K_GCmk